# Finding correlations between aggregated and non aggregated data

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to correlate server usage data with CPU utilization.  E.g., X number of transactions on the server correlates with Y amount of CPU utilization.  The transactions are reported hourly and the CPU utilization is reported on a per minute basis.  The current approach is to average the CPU utilization over the hour and then plot that against the hourly transaction data.

My concern is that there can be a spike in the load that lasts only a few minutes which would drive the CPU utilization up to a critical level during that time, but that spike (and the server performance degredation) would be lost when the CPU is averaged.

Is there a better way to approach this?  More granular load data may not be available so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe integrate CPU-usage over the hour?

Comment: @Affine That's what is being done now.  I'm wondering if there's any way to interpolate the load at a more granular level to get better correlation.

Comment: Why not correlate peak CPU utilization with usage? Or you might try correlating the amount of time in the hour above a given threshold with usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of using the minimun common resolution, hourly in this case, is quite usual and hourly samples are de-facto a standard for IT systems capacity planning.

You will not get a better resolution by interpolating the data nor using the peak will be of any help either without knowing more information on the transaction distribution.
**More granular data does not imply finding a better correlation** as you'll probably start adding noise (sampling noise for example) which the hourly average is reducing.

If the correlation is good, you can estimate the service demand to be used in a QN model.
If the correlation does not explain the usage of the CPU according to a QN model, try to analyze your CPU in frequency to see if you can identify periodic activity on the server which is not contributed by the transactions being managed.